# Getting and setting the RGB / RGBA value of a pixel in a CCSprite (cocos2d-x)

Tags: rgb, ccsprite, grayscale, rgba, cocos2d-x

Why do I need this?

Basically I need to turn a color image into gray-scale. Including a gray-scale version of the image could be a solution, but space is tight in my situation - I don't want my APK to be too big. Besides, I would like to work on the pixels for some effects too. Again, this is to make the APK smaller.

I have found [getPixel setPixel from CCTexture2D](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/3472) and [Getting image's pixel RGBA](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/8509), but I would like something more simple.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution for you :

1.First make a CCImage version of your image:

I) from File :

```
CCImage *img=  new CCImage();
img->initWithImageFile("colors.png");
```

II) From Sprite :

- II.1) CCSprite -> RenderTexture2D
- II.2) RenderTexture2D -> CCImage  (`CCImage *testImage = RenderText2D->newCCImage();`)

2.Then You can do what you need :

```
    CCImage *img= ... // make CCImage from CCSprite
    int x=3;
    if(img->hasAlpha())
        x=4;

    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[img->getDataLen()*x];   
    data = img->getData();
    // [0][0] => Left-Top Pixel !
    // But cocos2d Location Y-axis is Bottom(0) to Top(max)

    for(int i=0;i<img->getWidth();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<img->getHeight();j++)
        {
            unsigned char *pixel = data + (i + j * img->getWidth()) * x;
            
           // You can see/change pixels' RGBA value(0-255) here !
            unsigned char r = *pixel;
            unsigned char g = *(pixel + 1);
            unsigned char b = *(pixel + 2) ;
            unsigned char a = *(pixel + 3);
        }
    }
```

3.Then, convert it to texture_2D

```
//CCImage -> Texture2d
    texture_2D= new CCTexture2D();
    texture_2D->initWithImage(img);
```

4.And Finally  back to CCSprite

```
CCSprite *result=  CCSprite::createWithTexture(texture_2D);
```

Comment: I understand how you can see the rgba values, since you're setting char r = *pixel. But how do you change the value of the pixel ? I'm a bit confused about what you're doing with the pointers. Can you explain ?

Comment: @John Sure. It's almost similar. As you understood, we could access the `R` value of each pixel using the `*pixel` pointer. This is a Read (`xxx=*pixel`) and Write (`*pixel=xxx`) access. (use `*(pixel+1)` for `G` and so on)

Comment: Aren't you leaking memory by doing *data = new unsigned..... and then in the next line doing data = img->getData() ?

Comment: @John For using the `getData()` you need to allocate some memory beforehand. Anyway you are right.. you of course have to free the `data` memory at the end of procedure: `delete data`.

Comment: haha... actually I asked someone else a question about this and they told me I was leaking data based on doing new, and then the next line as I mentioned..... I do the delete but I didn't allocated... right now I'm just assigning right away (not allocating), because isn't it already allocated by img ? I feel like towelie... i have no idea whats going on.. .XD

Comment: @John Well. I wrote the code years ago and in that time I find that I need to allocate memory. But Cocos2dx improves month by month and they may have changed the behavior of `getData()`. Anyway, I can not test it now, please check if it needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a couple of ways.  What I have done in the past is to just called setColor on the sprite to some color close to what you are looking for.  That had worked for my purposes.

my_sprite.setColor( ccc3( 128, 128, 128 ) );

Another solution (more thorough and precise):
[how to implement grayscale rendering in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867653/how-to-implement-grayscale-rendering-in-opengl)

Comment: I know setColor(), but that is not what I want. Thanks for your link!