# Change RGB value of pixels of Sprite on a Given Radius in Cocos2dx

Tags: android, iphone, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have searched alot for this. But there are not any feasible solutions to this.
I got this much [Getting and setting the RGB / RGBA value of a pixel in a CCSprite (cocos2d-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665700/getting-and-setting-the-rgb-rgba-value-of-a-pixel-in-a-ccsprite-cocos2d-x). 
But i want to change the RGB values of pixels of my sprite where I click or move on the sprite. Basically its like coloring.The color of pixels change as we move on the sprite.

Comment: Improve your question by providing solutions that you tested, chunks of code, or a deeper explanation of what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

i can't see your code,so i don't know what's wrong with it ,but there have a better way to change pix color,that is shader,if you know how to use glprogream in cocos2dx ,i can write a shader to you ,then you can change the pix color